# how to enlarge the image in the cell

Tags: click, tableview, cell, tap, image-enlarge

i have insert an image view on the table view cell. and I would like it to enlarge the image to full screen. because it's too small.please help me. thanks very very much !This is my code below:

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:    (NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *identifier = @"identifier";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault   reuseIdentifier:identifier];


    //
    cell.selectionStyle =UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    //set the background
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

}else {

    [[cell.contentView     subviews]makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];

}

NSArray *images = @[@"po", @"po", @"po", @"po",@"po", @"po", @"po", @"po", @"po", @"po",@"po", @"po", @"po", @"po", @"po", @"po",@"po", @"po", @"po", @"po", @"po", @"po", @"po",@"po", @"po", @"po", @"po", @"po", @"po",@"po", @"po", @"po", @"po", @"po", @"po",@"po", @"po", @"po"];

//and an text view 
UITextView *hisText = [[UITextView alloc] init];
hisText.frame = CGRectMake(100, 110, 600, 350);
[hisText setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:14]];
hisText.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
hisText.editable = NO;


//set the image view 
UIImageView *hisImg =[[UIImageView alloc] init];
hisImg.frame = CGRectMake(106, 170, 575, 140);


switch (indexPath.row) {
    case 0:
        hisText.frame = CGRectMake(100, 120, 600, 500);
        hisText.text = @"Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Nam liber te conscient to factor tum poen legum odioque civiuda.”";
        hisImg.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1928-1.jpg"];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:hisText];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:hisImg];
        break;
    case 1:
        hisText.frame = CGRectMake(100, 155, 600, 405);
        hisText.text = @"Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.”";
        [cell.contentView addSubview:hisText];
        break;
    default:
        break;
}//


cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:images[indexPath.row]];

return cell;
}
```

someone help me .please, anyone here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in click event. you can get index from `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. Then take a image view and add as subview of the table view. Hope you can understand. :)